# Magento 2: Billing address same as shipping doesn't work while changing the shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, knockoutjs, quote

So I have 3 shipping methods on my checkout page,

Shipping Method

```
Free Ground Shipping- $0
2-Day Shipping - $15
Overnight - $35
```

By default, the first one `Free Ground Shipping- $0` is always selected, but if I select either `2-Day Shipping/Overnight` as the shipping method, I get the issue of  Billing address same as shipping, 
as `Billing Address` is not set as `Shipping address`. but the checkbox is selected somehow I don't know-how.

These are the error I get

[image]

[image]

I know this has something to do with `app/code/MODULE/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js`

```
 applyBillingAddress: function () {
        var shippingAddress;

        if (quote.billingAddress() && quote.billingAddress().hasOwnProperty('telephone')) {
            selectBillingAddress(quote.billingAddress());

            return;
        }
        shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

        if (shippingAddress &&
            shippingAddress.canUseForBilling() &&
            (shippingAddress.isDefaultShipping() || !quote.isVirtual())
        ) {
            //set billing address same as shipping by default if it is not empty
            selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
        }
    }
```

How to fix this.